# sending simultaneous keyboard events with SendInput on windows in C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, sendinput

I want to simulate keyboard presses in C++ using **SendInput**, while single buttons work, trying to send keys simultaneously (shortcuts) doesn't work.

I tried everything, but nothing works, if I send **VK_LWIN** alone it shows up, but couldn't combine keys simultaneously.

**here's my code:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void setInput(INPUT * inp,uint index, WORD keycode,BOOL kUp);
void showRun();

int main(void)
{
    showRun();
    return 0;
}

void setInput(INPUT * inp,uint index, WORD keycode,BOOL kUp)
{
    inp[index].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp[index].ki.wVk = keycode;
    inp[index].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(keycode, 0);
    inp[index].ki.time = 0;
    inp[index].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    if (kUp == 1)
    {
        inp[index].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
    }else
    {
        inp[index].ki.dwFlags =  0 | KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
    }
}

//this doesn't do anything
void showRun()
{
    INPUT *inp = (INPUT*) malloc(sizeof(INPUT) * 4);
    memset(inp,0,sizeof(INPUT));

    setInput(inp,0,VK_LWIN,0);
    setInput(inp,1,VK_RBUTTON,0);
    setInput(inp,2,VK_RBUTTON,1);
    setInput(inp,3,VK_LWIN,1);

    SendInput(4,inp,sizeof(INPUT));

    free(inp);
}
```

**while this works fine:**

```
void showStart()
{
    INPUT *inp = (INPUT*) malloc(sizeof(INPUT) * 2);
    memset(inp,0,sizeof(INPUT));

    setInput(inp,0,VK_LWIN,0);
    setInput(inp,1,VK_LWIN,1);

    SendInput(2,inp,sizeof(INPUT));

    free(inp);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any tip.

Comment: `VK_RBUTTON` is the right mouse button.

Comment: Side note, since you're sending a fixed amount of keys, there's no need to dynamically allocate your inputs, just make your array local.

Comment: @chris thanks to you I figured out my mistake!

Comment: @JeffMercado this was just a test, the code is meant to be dynamic and takes commands from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah stupid me, I should've used VkKeyScan('r') rather than VK_RBUTTON now it works!